# How to getDataEndpoint in AWS for Kinesis video Streaming

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to get the dataEndPoint for my kinesis video streaming to then allow me to add a video stream. I have read the documentation on PutMedia and getDataEndpoint and this is my code to get my dataEndPoint:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
var options = {
    accessKeyId: '*************',
    secretAccessKey: '****************',
    region: 'eu-west-1'
}
aws.config = new aws.Config(options);

var kinesisvideo = new aws.KinesisVideo();

    var params = {
        APIName: 'PUT_MEDIA',
        StreamARN: 'arn:aws:kinesisvideo:eu-west_1:********:stream/********/*********',
        StreamName: 'testStream'
    };

    kinesisvideo.getDataEndpoint(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log("error", err); // an error occurred
        else console.log("endpoint", data);           // successful response
    });
```

I am getting a 403 error  'UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the request is invalid.'

I am certain that the options passed to the aws.config are correct.
Why am I still getting this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, In fact I actually had the incorrect credentials passed in the 'options'. Correcting these credentials solved the issue. This syntax and procedure is correct